# Calculate barycentric coordinates of a point with respect to a 3D triangle using matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, euclidean-geometry, systems-of-equations, barycentric-coordinates

[This paper](https://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/cloth-sig02/cloth.pdf) shows an elegant way to calculate barycentric coordinates ($w_1$ : $w_2$ : $w_3$) of a point $x_4$ with respect to a 3D triangle formed by three points $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ (given $\vec{x}_{ij} = \vec{x}_j - \vec{x}_i$):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{x}_{13} \cdot \vec{x}_{13} & \vec{x}_{13} \cdot \vec{x}_{23} \\
\vec{x}_{13} \cdot \vec{x}_{23} & \vec{x}_{23} \cdot \vec{x}_{23}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
w_1 \\
w_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{x}_{13} \cdot \vec{x}_{43} \\
\vec{x}_{23} \cdot \vec{x}_{43}
\end{bmatrix}\\
w_1 + w_2 + w_3 = 1
$$

Based on the barycentric coordinates definition:

$$
\vec{x}_{13} w_1 + \vec{x}_{23} w_2 = \vec{x}_{43}
$$

So we can write this system of equations in the form of:

$$
(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{x}_{13}) w_1 + (\vec{v} \cdot \vec{x}_{23}) w_2 = (\vec{v} \cdot \vec{x}_{43})
$$

The nice thing about this system is that it works correctly even if the point $x_4$ doesn't lie on the triangle plane. However, there are 2 restrictions:

- $\vec{v}$ in different equations needs to be linearly independent.
- $\vec{v}$ needs to be perpendicular to the triangle normal, hence $\vec{x}_{13}$ and $\vec{x}_{23}$ are chosen for $\vec{v}$. I have tested other value of $\vec{v}$ that is not perpendicular to the triangle normal and the results are not correct.

**The question:** Why does $\vec{v}$ need to be perpendicular to the triangle normal?